# R package: can I design a custom install that downloads data to disk automatically?

Tags: r, server, r-package, rdata

I have an R package that contains .RData files. Right now it can be installed from GitHub. Once it is installed, users can simply use the `data()` function to import the data.

I would like to submit this package to CRAN but the .RData files are too large. I can instead host the .RData files on a server, but if I do that, the only way I know how to serve the files to the users is by having separate command to download the .RData files to the users' folders (meaning that first time users could not just use `data()` to import data--they would have to run something else, like download_data_from_server(), then import the data.

Is there a way to cut out the middle man and do a custom install that downloads the files to the users computer without this added step?

Comment: One option is to put the download command somewhere like `.onload` function. https://r-pkgs.org/Code.html#when-you-do-need-side-effects

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. This was very helpful.